# Layout problems with ggplotly and shinydashboard boxes

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard, ggplotly

I'm having a problem with ggplotly objects simply not staying inside boxes with shiny and shinydashboard. Before something is plotted, everything is right. But when a plot is displayed, the box doubles its size and the plot stays on top.
It happens only with ggplotly. A common ggplot works fine.

I've made it reproducible with the iris dataset below.

ui.R

```
dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
          dashboardSidebar(
              sidebarMenu(
                  menuItem("Species Overview",
                           tabName = "species"),
                  
                  menuItem(
                      pickerInput(
                          inputId = "species",
                          choices = species,
                          multiple = TRUE)))),
          dashboardBody(
              tabItems(
                  tabItem(tabName = "species",
                          fluidRow(
                              box(
                                  title = "Plot1",
                                  #width = 6,
                                  
                                  id = "plot1",
                                  plotlyOutput(
                                      "plot1", width = "100%") ## box 1 with ggplotly object
                              ),
                              box(
                                  title = "Plot2",
                                  id = "plot2",
                                  #width = 6,
                                  plotOutput(
                                      "plot2", width = "100%") ## box 2 with ggplot object
                              ))))))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
v <- reactiveValues()

observe({
    v$species <- input$species
})

species_selected <- reactive({
    validate(
        need(length(v$species) > 0, "Please select a species")
    )
    select_species(iris, v$species)})

plot1 = reactive({
    plot_1(species_selected())
})
plot2 = reactive({
    plot_2(species_selected())
})

output$plot1 = renderPlotly({
    plot1() |> ggplotly() ##ggplot object
})
output$plot2 = renderPlot({
    plot2() #ggplot object
})})
```

global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
#library(bs4Dash)

data(iris)
species = iris$Species |> unique() |> as.character()

select_species = function(df, species) {
  df = df |> 
    filter(Species %in% species)
  return(df)
}

plot_1 = function(df) {
  df = df
  p = df |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
    geom_point()
  return(p)
}

plot_2 = function(df) {
  p = df |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
    geom_point()
  return(p)
}
```

And this is what happens:

[image: layout problems]

I'm open to any suggestions. I've tried bs4dash, shinydashboard, shinydashboardPlus. Packages are all up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the height of the box and display the plotly object as shown below.

```
                                box(
                                    title = "Plot1",
                                    #width = 6,
                                    height = 460,
                                    id = "plot1",
                                    plotlyOutput(
                                      "plot1", width = "100%", height="400px") ## box 1 with ggplotly object
                                  ),
```

[image: output]

Comment: although I still don't understand why it's happening, this solution works. could it become a problem with different screen sizes?

Comment: `plotlyOutput` works better with direct `plot-ly` object than ggplotly object converting a `ggplot` object, as far as I know.  There could be more improvement in the future.